# task.factory startnew usage makes my website delog users from time to time

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library

This is the order of my code:

I make multiple

```
task.factory.startnew(()=> myFunction(myObject, httpSessionState))
```

I send the `System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState`  to myFunction because i dont wait for the tasks to end , so they run in background, and I can't get session inside myFunction because

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current = null.
```

myFunction calls webservices and stores their result in the  `httpSessionState` object

then I make several ajax calls to get the session values from the server, until I have all the desired values.

**PROBLEM**:

I cant explain why users get de-logged from time to time. I assume the session becomes null.
All users get delogged at the same time. All session objects probably become null

Comment: Sounds like the application pool is recycling, this is often caused by a memory leak or other excessive memory usage.

Comment: I'm not sure that Session state is valid when a request is not in progress. You should pull the Session data you need out into an object and pass that object to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens (loosing sessions) when the server process
w3wp.exe restarts (Asp.net application pool).

Usually hosting providers have an upper memory limit per application pool that when reached restarts the pool to avoid hogging the server.

So basically this could mean that your application is eating to much memory (or has memory leaks).

In your situation, this could mean that the Tasks you spawn are too heavy or leaking, which would indicate that you need to check myFunction().

If you need to limit the degree of concurrency to fine tune memory usage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

Comment: this problem appeared after i started using threads. so the problem must be from them. The task.factory clears threads after execution, so i dont think i have a memory leak... perhaps threading consumes more memory than before?

Comment: Of course that threading consumes more memory. Think for a second. You are executing X separate operations in parallel. If each operation required 1MB of memory while running, then you are now using X megabytes. Before this you were always using 1MB, but more times.

Comment: You can limit the degree of concurrency by using a different scheduler. Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely happening because of an **unhandled exception** in your asynchronous `Task`(s), which, by default (since .NET 2.0), *terminates* the process that owns the faulted thread.

The process in ASP.NET being your IIS worker process. When the worker process is terminated, it kills all current user sessions, invalidating any authentication they had with the running web app, and forcing them to log in again.

Because you are not waiting for a started task to complete (`Task.Wait()` or `Task<T>.Result`), and presumably not catching and handling the exceptions within the Tasks, .NET performs its default operation with unhandled exceptions, which is to *terminate* the process.

There's a good synopsis of how this changed from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0+ as well as some options for handling errors [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx), as well as more TPL error-handling techniques [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Exception-Handling_Tasks).

---

Fixing the process terminations depends on your requirements.

**Wait**. The safest approach would be to wait on all tasks completing: `Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, ...)`. You can start them all in parallel, so the wait time would only be as long as the longest task, thus leveraging parallelism for some speedup.

If you simply can't wait, and really want to let them runaway in the background, you need some protection:

**Swallow**. Wrap the body of the task's action/function in a `try-catch`, and do some logging in the catch, but "swallow" the exception rather than re-throwing it. This is dirty because you're basically ignoring faults in your application, and could lead to downstream problems when you've assumed the task was successful.

**Continue to Ignore**. This is basically the same as swallowing the exception, with the benefit of the `Task.Status` flag getting set to `Faulted` rather than erroneously advertising `RanToCompletion`. If you have setup some kind of Task-tracking mechanism, this may be helpful in recovering, or at least not assuming it went ok (more details about error continuations in the first link above).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myFunction(myObject, httpSessionState))
    .ContinueWith(faultedTask => 
    { 
        var ex = faultedTask.Exception; // reading the exception will ensure the process won't terminate
        Log.Error("Task Xyz failed", ex);
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted |
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

**Handle It**. You should set up some way to track failed tasks, recover from failures, or retry the tasks. If you can capture the success/failure of an async task, your ajax client could at least be equipped with information to make a smart next move. Possibly you could use some kind of state (page, Session, database) to store and lookup the status of a task by the same key you were going to use to store the task results in Session. Then only go to Session to get the results based on a `RanToCompletion` status; wait or recover otherwise.